# Vim How to keep :tag command from resizing splits to equal size when file is changed

Tags: vim

When using the :tag command (or the equivalent ), if the tag is in a different file then vim will resize window splits as if I had also done the = keystroke

This can be very difficult - and example would be:

1. Bring up the help docs in a split with ":help "
2. Increase the size of the help window
3. Follow a tag that is in a different help file

I don't see any reason why vim would find it necessary to resize my splits because I'm following tags.  Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: Do you have `:set equalalways`?

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I did, but I tried turning it off and still saw the same problem